# C2280 attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The code below triggers this error :

```
1>main.cpp(38): error C2280: 'CSet<uint32>::CSetHelper &CSet<uint32>::CSetHelper::operator =(const CSet<uint32>::CSetHelper &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>main.cpp(27): note: compiler has generated 'CSet<uint32>::CSetHelper::operator =' here
```

Code

```
typedef unsigned int uint32;

template<class I> class CSet
{
protected:
    uint32  u4Bits;
public:
    class CSetHelper
    {
    protected:
        uint32& ru4Var;
        uint32  u4Mask;
    public:
        CSetHelper(uint32& ru4_var, uint32 u4_mask)
            : ru4Var(ru4_var), u4Mask(u4_mask) {}
        operator uint32 () const
        {
            return ru4Var & u4Mask;
        }
        void operator =(uint32 i)
        {
            if (i)
                const_cast<uint32&>(ru4Var) |= u4Mask;
            else
                const_cast<uint32&>(ru4Var) &= ~u4Mask;
        }
    };
    CSet() : u4Bits(0) {}
    CSetHelper operator [](I i)
    {
        return CSetHelper(u4Bits, 1 << i);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CSet<uint32> sFlags;
    sFlags[0] = sFlags[1];
    return 0;
}
```

This is in VS2015, I know about the changes they made to the compiler ([detailed here](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F3%2FC%2F2%2F3C271B79-6354-4B66-9014-C6CEBC14C5C4%2FBreaking%2520Changes.docx)). But I am not understanding why it's triggering.

In theory it should use the right conversion and assignment operators but it doesn't seem to be.

UPDATE

Using Ideone.com and GCC 5.1 :

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper& CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper::operator=(const CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper&)':
prog.cpp:8:8: error: non-static reference member 'uint32& CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper::ru4Var', can't use default assignment operator
  class CSetHelper
        ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
prog.cpp:45:12: note: synthesized method 'CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper& CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper::operator=(const CSet<unsigned int>::CSetHelper&)' first required here 
  sFlags[0] = sFlags[1];
```

So it seems the problem is the reference member. I can fix it by making it a pointer, but I'm wondering why it can't default copy it.

Comment: my first guess, a compiler bug, with all the unnecessary code stripped down the program compiles fine.

Comment: @Raxvan How much "unnecessary" code did you strip down to make this compile?

Comment: If you don't use the class, it won't be instantiated so yeah I don't know what you removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `CSetHelper` contains a reference `uint32& ru4Var;`.

The compiler creates the assignment operator and copy constructor as deleted (`= delete`) for such types, because the reference cannot be re-seated.

Comment: "doesn't create" isn't quite right - it creates them as deleted.

Comment: Yeah I added some info I got by compiling using GCC, which is more helpful in this case. You're right :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct. This code is ill-formed. Let's take a look at this line:

```
sFlags[0] = sFlags[1];
```

There are two approaches the compiler could take to fulfill that operation:

```
CSetHelper& operator=(const CSetHelper&) = delete;  // (1)
void operator=(uint32 );                            // (2), via operator uint32()
```

While the 2nd is possible and likely intended by you, the first is the better candidate in overload resolution because it's an Exact Match and the latter involves a user-defined conversion. The copy assignment operator is still in the overload scope - it's simply implicitly deleted due to having a reference member. Deleted functions still participate in overload resolution, they just make the program ill-formed if selected.

Comment: you were right, i did not notice the `uint32& ru4Var;`.